# Importing Multiple Json Files At Once Into Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I know that we can use the `mongoimport` command to insert **one json file** into a mongodb database:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db [dbname] --collection [collectionname] --file filename.json
```

But are there any command that let me insert **multiple json files at once**?

Comment: There's no way to add multiple files in the same command you can however merge them into one with a command or use a for loop to call `mongoimport` with all files one by one.

Comment: you could use `cat` and have mongoimport read from stdin

Comment: Could u provide more details pls? @Joe

Answer (score 0):

On mac

```
cd jsonfilesfolder
ls -1 *.json | while read jsonfile; do mongoimport -d shop --file $jsonfile --type json; done
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/@seunghunsunmoonlee/how-to-import-multiple-json-files-from-the-folder-in-linux-mac-for-mongodb-using-mongoimport-3755eb5c04a6)